# Shortcode in template

Tags: 8, theming

I have installed and configured [Shortcode](https://www.drupal.org/project/shortcode) in a D8 project. However, when I try to use a short code like [column] or [button], it gets rendered as is in the node view page.

I have used a block panel in the node view page. And the in the block template I have rendered the body field like `{{ content['#node'].body[0].value|raw }}`.

However, I have noticed, that if I render the `content` as a whole like `{{ content }}`, the short codes gets rendered properly as intended.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t render field values like that. You should be doing it as `{{ content }}` or `{{ content.field_name }}`.

Comment: But I am not getting a `{{ content.field_name }}` in the twig file. Remember, its not a `node.html.twig` but a `block--entity-view--node--article.html.twig`

Comment: To add, what I am trying to do is render the body field that contains shortcode. The shortcodes are rendered as is in the page.

Comment: Then it’s `{{ block_content.field_name }}`

Comment: Could'nt get the `block_content` variable also. I instead created a separate block to render the field and in turn rendered that block inside this twig template.